# Como convertir 0.0 a 0.00 en java

Tags: java, eclipse

estuve investigando como resolver un problema muy en los tipos de datos en java y me estoy topando que en una validación que estoy realizando me los pone en 0.0 y lo que se pretende es que se quede con este formato 0.00 o 0 en su defecto, este la validación que estoy haciendo:

```
            if(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto()==0.24) {
                //int numero =0;
                //cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setSaldoInsoluto((double) 0.00);
            
                
                cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setSaldoInsoluto(0.00);//Aqui es donde está el problema con el 0.0
                
cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setImporte(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoAnterior());
                LOG.info("Si entré a la validación oJO getSaldoInsoluto!!!!!" + cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto());
            }
```

Pero como resultado se visualiza así 0.0, hay alguna manera de que se casteé y quede en 0.00 o 0?

En la consola me sigue apareciendo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me pueda dar a entender, de momento les agradezco y quedo al pendiente si hay algo que no se entienda gracias.

Comment: Estas confundiendo formato de visualizacion, con tipo de dato guardado. 0 o 0.0 o 0.00 son solo formatos del numero 0. La computadora, guarda 0.. no le imporat el foramto... el formato lo tenes que dar vos al mostrar el valor...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi es lo ultimo que comentas, lo que quiero es darle un formato que sería 0.00, pero al imprimir lo toma como 0.0, voy a actualizar la pregunta para poner mediante en la consola como se pinta

Comment: al imprimir puedes aplicar format System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", numero));

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto:

```
 private static final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

Una vez tienes el formato en el que deseas tu valor, tienes que hacer esto:

```
double value = format.format(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto());
LOG.info("Si entré a la validación oJO getSaldoInsoluto!!!!!" + value);
```